# Which of these formulas are sentences?

Tags: logic

Let V be the vocabulary {+,<,1,2,3} where + is an arbitrary function, < is a binary relation, and 1,2, and 3 are constants. We write (x+y) for +(x,y) and x<y for <(x,y). Consider the following V-formulas:

1. ∀x∃y((x+y)=1)
2. ∀x¬(x<1)
3. ((1+1)=2)
4. 2<1
5. ∀x(2<1) →(x+2<x+1)
6. ∀x∀y∃z(x+y=z)
7. ∀x∀y∀z(((x+3=y)∧(x+3=z))->(y=z))
8. ∀x∀y∀z(((x+y=3)∧(x+z=3))->(y=z))
9. ∀x∀y(((x+3)<(y+3))->(x<y))
10. ∀x∀y((x<2)->((x+3)=4))

Question: Which of these 10 formulas are sentences?
I have the following definitions from the book:
Definition. A vocabulary is a set of function, relation and constant symbols.
Definition. A sentence of first-order logic is a formula having no free variables.
In contrast to the free variables of a formula p, the bound variables of p are those that have quantifiers, (∃,∀).
I tried to interpret this information and it seems that the formulas 1-10 have no free variables and each of them is therefore a sentence. Is this right or wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: A formula is **not** a sentence if it has free occurrences of variables.

Comment: 1) **is** a sentence because all the variables occur in the scope of the coirresponding quantifier. 5) is not.

Answer (score 1):

The $V$-formulas above that are not $V$-sentences are $5$ and $10$; technically speaking, $10$ is not even a $ V$-formula.

The reason why $5$ is not a $V$-sentence is that the scope of the quantifier $\forall x$ is $(2<1)$, so that the occurrences of $x$ in the right-hand side of the implication are free. On the other hand, if the expression was of the form $\forall x ((2<1) \to (x+2<x+1))$, then this would be a $V$-sentence since the scope of the quantifier $\forall x$ in this case is $(2<1)\to(x+2<x+1)$.

The reason why $10$ is not a $V$-sentence (and not even a $V$-formula) is that the symbol $4$ does not belong to the vocabulary $V$. If on the other hand $4$ was replaced by, say 1 or the variable $y$, then the resulting expression would be indeed a $V$-sentence.

Comment: "left-hand side" should be "right-hand side". Good catch on 10.